# Nautilus CLI is Extremely Slow for SSHFS Mounted Paths, but the GUI is Fast

Tags: networking, nautilus, sshfs

I do most of my navigation in the terminal, however in certain circumstances it
is nice to open a directory in a GUI. On Ubuntu Linux the default file browser
is nautilius. My workflow is typically: cd into a folder of interest on my
terminal, and then run `nautilus .` (or `xdg-open .`, which effectively does
the same thing), which pops open a finder window.

While most of the work I do is on my local machine, sometimes I need to
navigate the filesystem on a remote machine. This fits into my workflow nicely.
I simply sshfs mount the remote machine, and pretend that everything is local.

However, this is where I encounter a problem.  Running `nautilus .` when inside
an sshfs mounted directory is very slow. I recognize that there will be some
lag due to the resources being non-local, but the slowdown I see goes far
beyond what I would expect.

#### Observations

To demonstrate the problem, I sshfs mounted a remote
machine, that is located about 20 miles away. When I cd into a mounted
directory and run: `time nautilus .` I get this:

```
real    1m13.918s
user    0m0.045s
sys 0m0.133s
```

It takes over 1 minute to open up the remote window. Note that when I ping the
machine, the lag time is roughly `40.5 ms` for 64 bytes.

Furthermore, if I first open a local nautilus window and copy the mounted path
into the navigation bar, it loads very quickly. Less than 3 seconds.

Now, it should be noted that this slowness doesn't exist if I do this with a
machine that is on my LAN and has a ping of roughly `0.618 ms`. Running
`nautilus .` on this nearby remote machine is:

```
time nautilus .

real    0m1.454s
user    0m0.008s
sys 0m0.024s
```

However, this is still somewhat slow compared to the time it takes when I copy
the sshfs-mounted path into a nautilus navigation bar. That takes less than a
second.

And for comparison, when I run `nautilius .` locally, the result is almost instant:

```
time nautilus .

real    0m0.082s
user    0m0.017s
sys 0m0.009s
```

#### Summary

To summarize these results here is a table of the time it takes to run
`nautilus .` versus pasting a sshfs-mounted path into a nautilus navigation bar
as well as ping time for my local machine, a nearby machine on the LAN, and a
far away machine on the WAN.

| distance | ('time', 'nautilus .') | ('time', 'navigation bar') | ('time', 'ping') |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| localhost | 0m0.082s | <1s | 0.050 ms |
| LAN | 0m1.454s | <1s | 0.618 ms |
| WAN | 1m13.918s | <3s | 40.5 ms |

It seems to me that running `nautilus .` must be performing a large number of
round trips to scale the way I've measured it.

Unfortunately, I can't provide a MWE for this as it requires external hardware,
but hopefully my description is detailed enough.

#### Question

I'm wondering if there is any way that I could either make `nautilus .` faster,
or script something such that the script quickly opens a local nautilus window
and then uses a macro to copy the path into the navigation bar so I could get
the speed of the manual method without the manual copy/paste sequence.

I have tried using dbus via this thread: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/364997/open-a-directory-in-the-default-file-manager-and-select-a-file
but I haven't had much luck with it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that Nautilus is having trouble detecting that things are on a remote server. Let's make it be more careful and treat everything like it could be remote:

1. Open the Nautilus Preferences

[image: files preferences]

2. Scroll down to Performance and set everything to "Never"

[image: performance settings]

It is indeed "performing a large number of round trips". When you paste the sshfs path into Nautilus's navigation bar, Nautilus realizes it is referencing a remote server. When you use the `sshfs`, it just adds another `/proc/mounts` entry as a third-party FUSE filesystem, and Nautilus does not have a special case for it. Then thumbnailing and folder counting require reading each file and listing each folder, and that tries to send a massive amount of packets over the network.

Comment: Thank you! This works perfectly. I've started a discussion on the gnome discourse to see if its possible to port the remote check nagivation bar to the CLI invocation: https://discourse.gnome.org/t/feature-request-make-nautilius-cli-aware-of-remote-paths/19268/2