# nautilius views icon or thumbnail

Tags: directory, thumbnails

I have several folders containing short videos. Some folders show video icons. Some folders show thumbnails.  How do I control which is which?  I'm on ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS and files v. 1:3.36.3.0ubuntu1.20.04.2

Comment: Are the folders on network drives? If so, you can try changing the setting by following my answer at https://askubuntu.com/a/1501880/1004020